# import text strings into Unity editor 3D text objects so that Scene View displays them

Tags: unity, text, editors

I am having trouble finding a solution to this problem.  I want to generate the text for TextMesh.text in a custom application and import into the Unity editor so that I can then scale the text to fit.  If anyone could point me in the right direction to simply edit a 3D Text game objects' text mesh.text property from a script so that it is reflected in the scene view in Unity's editor, I would greatly appreciate it!

Best Regards,
Ben

Comment: If you're generating the mesh for your text in a different application, why do you care about textmesh at all?  Couldn't you just use a meshrenderer and render it like any other piece of geometry?

Comment: I am generating the text for the text mesh in a different application.  I want to use the Unity Editor to resize the text mesh.

Comment: Same question then.  Why can't you just treat it like a normal mesh and resize it that way?